# Force shutdown without checking open process Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, shutdown, kill

Is there any way to force shutdown without checking or waiting running procceses to terminate. More specifically, i want something like unpluging the socket. Setting the value of WaitTimeToKillApp in registry as zero doesn't do the job, the window that says:"If you force shutdown you will lose your unsaved job" keeps popping up. Can anyone explain what checks the windows does explicitly, in order to shutdown so i can cancel them.

Make the system kill itself ignoring ANY procceses (not only procecses EVERYTHING)

Comment: open a command prompt and type shutdown /s

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the normal shutdown, you could create a batch file, using as an off switch. The batch file should contain the command: "shutdown /s /t 0 /f"

Create that batchfile and create a shortcut to it in Start or on the Desktop. Now just click on it and the computer goes down.

EDIT:
PS:
Naming that batch file "Internet Explorer" and giving it the IE Icon is a great way to have fun with friends and family. And don't worry, nobody who is worth using a computer is ever clicking on it ;)

Comment: Is there something faster? Similar to sudo shutdown in unix?
Something that doesnt have to check every running process. Like force kill the windows operating system (so the other process can stop running) or something like flushing RAM.

Comment: @BillSk Maybe unplugging the power cord or battery? Really it's a bad idea to force kill the OS and all running processes because you may lose your data that way.